# Dog chases his tail ! - "parametric differential/Integral equation"..?

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, parametric-functions, integral-equations

I have the following situation where I am interested in the function $m(t)$

$$ \frac{dm}{dt}=4T(t)^{3}+T(t)^{2} $$
$$ T(\tau)=T_{0}-\int_{0}^{\tau}(\frac{dm}{dt})dt*Q_{S} $$

Is there a way to solve it analytically using Mathematica?
Thanks for your help in advance
Andi

ps.: I guess I just don't know what to look for

Comment: Take a look a [`DSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolve.html?q=DSolve) - and maybe get familiar with *Mathematica* a bit.

Comment: The notation is certainly confusing me. If I interpret $\frac{dm}{dt}(T)$ as the derivative of $m(T)$ with respect to $t$, then that's $0$; if that's the product of $\frac{dm}{dt}$ and $T$, then the right hand side is effectively a constant. So, what then?

Comment: I hope it is more clear after that edit ... - m is the mass, T the temperature - mass changes depending on the Temperature. The temperature drops by losing mass (Sublimation)

Comment: What do you get if you differentiate your second equation with respect to $t$?

Comment: something arbitrary- but I just realized, that the Integral is written wrong - next edit ...

Comment: That was supposed to be a leading question, actually. Differentiate carefully. Does it now look like a bonafide DE after the operation? EDIT: considering the current form of your second equation, you do remember that integration undoes differentiation, right?

Comment: It is very nice of you to point that out. Anyway - I am interested in numbers - so it does not help much, since (dm/dt) depends on T(same t) where i again - need (dm/dt). I think, that is my basic problem.

Comment: But you agree, that you can simplify your second equation to $T(\tau)=T_0-Q_S(m(\tau)-m(0))$, yes?

Comment: yes - so I could say $m(\tau)=m(0)-\frac{T(\tau)-T_0}{Q_S}$ - still i don't know how to evaluate $T(\tau)$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following up on @J.M.'s observations in the comments, differentiate

$$m(t)=m(0)-\frac{T(t)-T_0}{Q_S}$$

to get
$$\frac{dm}{dt}=-\frac{T'(t)}{Q_S}$$

Combine with

$$\frac{dm}{dt}=4 \, T(t)^{3}+T(t)^{2}$$

to get a differential equation in `T[t]`:

$$ T'(t)=-\text{Qs} \left(4 \, T(t)^3+T(t)^2\right)$$

Use `DSolve` with initial value `T[0] == t0`:

```
DSolve[{T'[t] == -Qs ( 4 T[t]^3 + T[t]^2), T[0] == t0}, T, t]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you very much @kglr, obviously it was a mathematics/approach problem :-) - and my bachelor studies were too long ago, ... maybe then I could have handled it better

Comment: @G.Andi, my pleasure. You were almost there:) Thank you for the accept.

Comment: now i will do this approach with my real dm/dt function which is a hell compared to $\frac{dm}{dt}=4 \, T(t)^{3}+T(t)^{2}$ :-)